# HBase installation in cluster - Master is initializing error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hbase, apache-zookeeper, distributed-system

I am installing a multi node HBase cluster - 3 master and 3 region servers.
After installation, all the nodes are up and connected, the HBase UI, everything connected and all fine.

I am able to HBase CLI, but when I try to create a table, I am getting the below error:

> ERROR: org.apache.hadoop.hbase.PleaseHoldException: Master is initializing
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.checkInitialized(HMaster.java:2811)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.createTable(HMaster.java:2018)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterRpcServices.createTable(MasterRpcServices.java:659)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.shaded.protobuf.generated.MasterProtos$MasterService$2.callBlockingMethod(MasterProtos.java)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcServer.call(RpcServer.java:418)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.CallRunner.run(CallRunner.java:133)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:338)
> at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.ipc.RpcExecutor$Handler.run(RpcExecutor.java:318)

I tried different workarounds as below:

1. Deleted the Znode entry for hbase
2. Removed the hbase.rootdir from hdfs.
3. Used HBCK2 with different options.

Nothing worked for me.

I tried scanning the hbase:meta table and that also  giving error as below:

> WARN  org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.ZKAsyncRegistry - Meta region is in state OPENING

Thanks in advance
Jithesh